# If $f$ = $f^{-1}$ then $f(x) = x$ for some $x$

Tags: real-analysis, functions

I would like to know if the following suffices to prove the proposition below. While I can't see anything wrong with it, it gives me a strange feeling.

**Proposition:**

If $f$ is a continuous function on $\mathbb{R}$ and $f = f^{-1}$, prove that there is at least one $x$ such that $f(x) = x$.

**Proof:**

If there did not exist such an $x$, then we would have $f(y) > y$ or $f(y) < y$ for all $y \in \mathbb{R}$. Assume the former. In such a case, it follows that
$$ f(f(y)) > f (y) > y $$
yet by definition we have $f = f^{-1}$ and so
$$ f(f(y)) = y $$
This is a contradiction and proves the assertion.

Comment: I don't see any problem with your argument.

Comment: @julien The IVT argument you mentioned must be written explicitely.

Comment: I agree with N.S., add: by the intermediate value theorem.

Comment: The proof can be reduced to the following: Let $g(x)=f(x)-x$.  Then  $g(x)$ and $g(f(x))$ have opposite signs, thus by IVT....

Comment: Okay, it seems that the consensus is that the IVT should be mentioned explicitly, but otherwise all is well. If someone, perhaps @N.S., wants to write this as an answer I can accept it.

Comment: Since your proof was right, I think it is OK if you write it as an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The consensus is that the proof is mostly correct. To improve it, the intermediate value theorem should be mentioned explicitly to remove any ambiguity as to why we have, for all $y$ in $\mathbb{R}$,
$$f(y) > y \text{ or } f(y) < y$$

User N.S. also points out that the proof could be reduced to the statement

"Let $g(x)=f(x)−x$. Then $g(x)$ and $g(f(x))$ have opposite signs, thus by IVT...."

Answer (score 1):

If $f(y) \neq y$ means either $f(y)> y$ or $f(y)<y$. But the inequality could depend on $y$. Why can you suppose the same inequality is true for every $y$?

Comment: Intermediate value theorem.

Comment: yes, that should be made explicit. Otherwise the continuity is not used anywhere.